# ClickOnce Program Not Starting

Tags: visual-studio, xna, clickonce

For some reason a ClickOnce program I made in VisualStudio will not run. The program runs normally if I compile it, and I have made ClickOnce programs in the past that have run on my computer, so I know it works. I get no error messages, and the program never shows in the Task Manager. Any ideas what could be wrong?

EDIT: I found the problem. It wasn't including some text files that my program opens and reads when it starts. I'm guessing the program terminated when it didn't find those files, but why did I not get an error message pop up?

Comment: You can post your solution as a self answer